# Extended inline assembler constraints using gcc

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, benchmarking, inline-assembly

Google benchmark defines `DoNotOptimize` as follows:

```
template <class Tp>
inline BENCHMARK_ALWAYS_INLINE void DoNotOptimize(Tp& value) {
#if defined(__clang__)
  asm volatile("" : "+r,m"(value) : : "memory");
#else
  asm volatile("" : "+m,r"(value) : : "memory");
#endif
}
```

I tried experimenting with different constraint modifiers using gcc and there seems to be a difference with inclusion of the register constraint vs. w/o it, in particular the following code snippet:

```
int value = 1;
void incr() 
{
    ++value;
    asm volatile("" : "+m"(value) : : "memory");
}
```

results in the disassembly which as far as I can tell increments `value` with the destination operand being a memory address.

```
incr():
        add     DWORD PTR value[rip], 1
        ret
value:
        .long   1
```

The following code snippet however

```
int value = 1;
void incr() 
{
    ++value;
    asm volatile("" : "+r,m"(value) : : "memory");
}
```

results in a move into the register, an add, followed by a write into memory

```
incr():
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR value[rip]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR value[rip], eax
        ret
value:
        .long   1
```

My question is what is the advantage of adding the `+r` register constraint to `DoNotOptimize` vs. simply using the memory constraint?

**Update:**
Using clang trunk, the dissassembly is the same as using the memory constraint alone. So the difference is with gcc. I haven't tried other compilers.

Comment: Clearly no benefit for a global variable and use a `"memory"` clobber to force the compiler to sync (globally reachable) memory with the C abstract machine.  Make it a local (and/or drop the `"memory"` clobber) so it can stay in a register.  When escape analysis can prove a var is private, a memory clobber doesn't force it to be synced.

Comment: If it is a local, gcc actually fails compilation with -O2, likely because it keeps it in a register; while clang compiles it okay.
```
<source>:6:5: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
    6 |     asm volatile("" : "+r,m"(value) : : "memory");
      |     ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Just tried it; had to remove the `,m` part for clang to keep it in a register inside a loop.  https://godbolt.org/z/KGWT6c.  clang is unfortunately bad at this part of inline asm, preferring memory whenever you give it a choice.  Sometimes using `"r,m"` instead of `"rm"` will make it choose register, but not here.

Comment: IDK what you mean about GCC failing to compile it. https://godbolt.org/z/6h81eY shows GCC 10.2 has no problem with my loop, with `sm volatile("" : "+r,m"(value) : : "memory");`. Unlike clang, GCC still picks a register for a local `int value=1;`

Comment: I meant with the register and memory constraint as used in the DoNotOptimize macro:https://godbolt.org/z/Y8Wxeb

Comment: Oh, that's *weird*.  Putting it in a loop avoided that problem (see the edit to my previous comment, I was using that full version).  Looks like a GCC bug, go report it at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.  Perhaps GCC is deciding the variable is dead / unused, and has already deleted it tried to do register allocation for the asm statement??  Seems to be a regression from GCC4.9 which works (https://godbolt.org/z/7PeTne) to GCC5.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug that typically won't show up on most benchmarks due to the inherent loop and the variable typically declared **outside** the loop. I will report the bug, thanks!